# Not receiving notification when it is sent while the application is killed/closed

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

My desired outcome is to be able to display a notification when one is received regardless of whether the app is in ***foreground/background/kill***. I am currently able to receive the notification on my mobile application when it is in foreground/background and from there I will create a local notification.

However, when the application is killed, it returns an error saying  ***D/FCMPlugin:    Unable to send event due to unreachable bridge context***.

My mobile application is developed using Ionic and the notification is sent through google fcm via php.

What am I doing wrongly?

```
  "data" => [
               "notification_id" => 101,
               "item_id" => 1111111,
               "ticket_classification" =>  "manual",
               "routing_page"=>"TicketListPage",
               "title" => "New Task" ,
               "body" => "Hi " . $user->name . ",\nYou have a new " . $ticket_description ." task to work on." ,
               "content-available"=> "1",
               "force-start"=>"1"
           ],
           "priority"=>"high"
```

Android FCM Plugin File

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    Log.d(TAG, "==> MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived");
    
    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Message: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("wasTapped", false);
    
    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        data.put("title", remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        data.put("body", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    for (String key : remoteMessage.getData().keySet()) {
        Object value = remoteMessage.getData().get(key);
        Log.d(TAG, "\tKey: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        data.put(key, value);
    }
    
    Log.d(TAG, "\tNotification Data: " + data.toString());
    FCMPlugin.sendPushPayload(data);
}
// [END receive_message]
```

Log D Messages

```
D/FCMPlugin: ==> MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived
D/FCMPlugin:    Key: content-available Value: 1
D/FCMPlugin:    Key: force-start Value: 1
D/FCMPlugin:    Key: notification_id Value: 101
D/FCMPlugin:    Key: routing_page Value: TicketListPage
D/FCMPlugin:    Key: ticket_classification Value: manual
D/FCMPlugin:    Key: body Value: Hi Lengky,
    You have a new A task to work on.
D/FCMPlugin:    Key: title Value: New Task
D/FCMPlugin:    Key: item_id Value: 1111111
D/FCMPlugin:    Notification Data: {wasTapped=false, item_id=1111111, ticket_classification=manual, notification_id=101, routing_page=TicketListPage, content-available=1, body=Hi Lengky,
    You have a new A task to work on., title=New Task, force-start=1}
D/FCMPlugin: ==> FCMPlugin sendPushPayload
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: wasTapped => false
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: item_id => 1111111
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: ticket_classification => manual
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: notification_id => 101
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: routing_page => TicketListPage
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: content-available => 1
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: body => Hi Lengky,
    You have a new A task to work on.
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: title => New Task
D/FCMPlugin:    payload: force-start => 1
D/FCMPlugin:    Unable to send event due to unreachable bridge context
```

Comment: See https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues.

Comment: @MartinZeitler can you elaborate more please? there are many issues listed there